# python pause infinite loop for code outside loop to be executed

Tags: python

I am wondering if this is possible. I want to have an infinite while loop but still wont the rest of the code outside the while loop to continue running while the loop is on. like a way to break the while loop after each iteration for instance. i need to find a way for the second print statement to be executed without breaking the while loop completely.

```
while True:
   print('i will loop forever')

print('this code will never be executed because of the while loop')
```

Comment: Use multi threading, there are many options to do that in python.

Comment: Seems like you want to use threads, read about them.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this, such as threading.  However, it looks like you may wish to serially loop for a while, break, then continue.  Generators excel at this.

for example:

```
def some_loop():
  i=0
  while True:
    yield i
    i+=1

my_loop=some_loop()

#loop for a while
for i in range(20):
  print(next(my_loop))

#do other stuff
do_other_stuff()

#loop some more, picking up where we left off
for i in range(10):
  print(next(my_loop))
```